# Image is not editing after click on update button

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am going through a Django tutorial and My blog post image is not editing for edit post in my blog app. I use Django==3.1.2.

views.py

```
def edit_post(request, post_id):
    post = BlogPost.objects.get(id=post_id)



    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = UpdatePost(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=post)

    else:
        form = UpdatePost(instance=post, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('mains:posts')

    context = {'post':post,'form':form}
    return render(request, 'mains/edit_post.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class UpdatePost(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['blog_post_title','blog_description','image']
```

edit_post.html

```
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**The Problem**

I am trying to edit my post in my blog app, Everything is working fine ( Blog title and Blog description is changing ) - when i change image it returns ( redirect ) fine BUT image not changing.
I am stuck with this problem and have no idea what is wrong.

**What have i tried.**

1). When i first create the view then i didn't add (request.POST or None, request.FILES or None), BUT
when i notice that, this may be effecting from editing then i added and it still not editing the image.

2). I have also changed template before BUT nothing works.

3). I have also changed form before BUT nothing workes.

Help me in this. I will really appreciate your Help. Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
def edit_post(request, post_id):
    post = BlogPost.objects.get(id=post_id)



    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = UpdatePost(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=post)

    else:
        form = UpdatePost(instance=post, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('mains:posts')

    context = {'post':post,'form':form}
    return render(request, 'mains/edit_post.html', context)
```